# Left and right positions of some user cards in the question queue

Tags: discussion, support, bug, user-interface

I would like to know if there is a specific reason or justification for some users being are displayed on the left and some on the right as shown in the red boxes.

[image]

Comment: Please tell us which venue you see this in, on mobile, e.g.?  I'm asking because it looks like your two examples show an effort to minimize the vertical distance of each question in the list of questions.  I ask if you are using it on mobile, because I see the site almost always on my laptop, and the OP, etc, is always positioned on the right.  It is likely not at all a bug.

Comment: @amWhy I am seeing the same thing as Sebastiano on my laptop. I am using chrome and have not seen the like before.

Comment: @amWhy Hi, I use always the laptop and not a smartphone. Also on Physics SE it is the same. In TeX.SE. I not seen the watched tags. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8787/watched-tags-no-coloring-questions. Until this morning I saw everything as perfect as every other day. But tonight I see that there are differences.

Comment: @AndréArmatowski Hi also to you. Yes I use also Chrome. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I also see this, but I use Mozilla.

Comment: @AndréArmatowski, Sebastiano, then yes, I'd say there's a bug!

Comment: I use Mozilla, and I don't see this.   Maybe the bug will spread to my laptop as well.  We've already gathered a bunch of data!  Has anyone searched [Meta.se] yet?  In case this is site wide?

Comment: @amWhy Then you are lucky :-)

Comment: @VerónicaRmz. Thank you very much for your feedback.

Comment: @amWhy See this please: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366321/ignored-and-watched-tags-seem-broken

Comment: Good for checking there; quite a bit seems awry; the quickest way to get action on the bug you found is to address it on [meta.se], if you see nothing about the display of OP's positions.

Comment: I see this as well, Firefox on Windows 7. As already suggested, it seems to happen when the list of tags extends too far to the right and the user name etc wraps around on to the next line (as it were.)

Comment: @PeterPhipps Before this not happened :-(

Comment: Looks like a difference caused by the amount of tags and the length of their names.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It is strange. However I think that there is a problem on all the sites. Also in PSE and in TeX.SE.

Comment: @Sebastiano FYI, the Meta post [Profile images are pushed to next line if tags extend too far to the right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366329/562482) seems to be the same as what you're asking about.

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes, that's correct. See the above comment.

Comment: I can repro on math.se on an iPhone in landscape mode by clicking on various tags but not on the front page because the avatar and rep isn’t shown?

Comment: @JohnOmielan Hi and thank you very much for your contribute. I have read the link and the post. For me it is very strange as it had not happened before even though about a month ago several changes were made on all sites. My best regards.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Very Kind Calvin for me there is something not working properly :-) boh. I hope they fix the site well and make the best use of the space they have available.

Comment: What difference would it make, whether displayed on the left or right? You're overreacting.

Comment: @NikhilKumarSingh Dear user it was just a matter of habit since my eye was used to look at them always on the right. On the "you're overreacting" issue are just points of view. Greetings.

Comment: @NikhilKumarSingh why would you say Sebastiano is overreacting? From quickly glancing at their post, it sounds quite emotionally neutral to me. I'd be curious too if it happened to me as well.

Comment: This is now [meta-tag:status-completed] on [metase]: [Profile images are pushed to next line if tags extend too far to the right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366329).

Comment: @TheAmplitwist I thank you very much for you advice and your precious collaboration also with me.

Comment: No problem, Sebastiano. I'm just keeping abreast of updates over on Meta SE :) Thank *you* for bringing this bug to the attention of this community!

Comment: Looks like the left-right position of the "last modified" portion is also upset now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3Mji.png

Comment: @TheAmplitwist Hence there is a bit of confusion :-))))))...Thank you for the advice that I not knew. My best regards from Sicily (Italy).

Comment: On [metase], the [corresponding report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366329/986753) was briefly [retagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/366329/8) as [meta-tag:status-planned], and it has now [once again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/366329/9) been tagged as [meta-tag:status-completed].

Comment: I'm sorry for my delay to get you an answer. Thank you very much for the complete explanation with the links.